# How to define array in multiple lines in Shell

Tags: macos, shell

Is it possible to define an array in multiple lines in a shell script file? I tried something like this:

**foo.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

messages=(
    "Hello"
    "World"
)

echo $messages
```

However, the output only has the first line "Hello", but not the second line "Word".

```
$ sh foo.sh
Hello
```

What is more confusing to me is that if I copy the content of foo.sh and paste it directly into the terminal, things work as I expected:

```
$ messages=(
    "Hello"
    "World"
)

echo $messages
Hello World
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: Because your terminal is not `sh`

Comment: Make your script executable and run it directly with `./foo.sh` that should produce identical results.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thanks for the comments! I tried `chmod + x foo.sh` and then do `./foo.sh`, it will give the same result: with only "Hello" without "World". Any further thoughts?

Comment: If your interactive shell is bash, you can look at the structure of the array you've created using `declare -p messages` to see if the problem you're experiencing is in the *assignment* or the *display* of the array contents. Also try putting that command into your script to see what happens. Note that in bash, if you want to print all array elements, `printf '%s ' "${messages[@]}"` would be the way to go. Simply running `echo $messages` would be equivalent to `echo ${messages[0]}`, giving you only the first array element.

Comment: @ghoti, "echo $messages would be equivalent to echo ${messages[0]}" => that's exactly what the problem is, thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you want to print the whole array, you need:

```
echo ${messages[@]}
```

Comment: `${messages[*]}` works as well to access the whole array. If the index number is @ or *, all members of an array are referenced as the [guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) says

Comment: And in case of `echo ${messages[*]}` referencing array with `*` is recommended by Google Shell Style Guide: `Use "$@" unless you have a specific reason to use $*, such as simply appending the arguments to a string in a message or log`; [link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#quoting).